# NSTableView drag items "count badge"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When you start dragging items in the table view in Mail or iTunes, you see this count badge neatly showing (in a red "starred" circle, or rounded rectangle if the count gets big enough) the number of dragged items. Is there a ready-made code somewhere available for me to do this? Because if it is, it could save me a whole lot of time writing the drawing code for this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there isn't. However it should be pretty easy to create a custom one. It'll be some fiddling with coordinates to get it right but actually shouldn't be too much code.

Maybe google already has some usable image data...

Comment: Looks like you're right. No ready-made on is out there. I ended up coding up my own badge. Thanks.